# How to dynamically add column/values to Map Type in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently I have file structure defined so dataframe schema is like below(Sample data used from different source)

```
schema = StructType([
     StructField('id', StringType(), True),
     StructField('dept', StringType(), True),
     StructField('salary', IntegerType(), True),
     StructField('location', StringType(), True)
     ])

df = spark.createDataFrame([(36636,'Finance'  ,3000,  'USA'),
(40288,'Finance' ,  5000, 'IND'),
(42114,'Sales',    3900,'USA'),
(39192,'Marketing',2500, 'CAN'),
(34534,'Sales',    6500,  'USA')],
schema=schema)
```

I do below operation to create map type for 2 columns like below

```
df = df.withColumn("propertiesMap",create_map(
        lit("salary"),col("salary"),
        lit("location"),col("location")
        )).drop("salary","location")
```

And my dataframe looks like this

```
+-----+---------+---------------------------------+
|id   |dept     |propertiesMap                    |
+-----+---------+---------------------------------+
|36636|Finance  |[salary -> 3000, location -> USA]|
|40288|Finance  |[salary -> 5000, location -> IND]|
|42114|Sales    |[salary -> 3900, location -> USA]|
|39192|Marketing|[salary -> 2500, location -> CAN]|
|34534|Sales    |[salary -> 6500, location -> USA]|
+-----+---------+---------------------------------+
```

Going forward the input file may have dynamic columns like

```
file1.csv
id,dept,Salary,location

file2.csv
id,dept,salary

file3.csv
id,dept

file4.csv
id,dept,firstname,lastname,middlename,address
```

In all the cases `id,dept` do not change. But all other columns are dynamic. I process file by file

For Example take file1.csv from above

```
fixed_columns = [id,dept]

all_columns= df.columns

dynamic_col = list(set(all_columns) - set(fixed_columns))
```

Gives

```
dynamic_col = [salary, location]

And I want something like and to use append?. Not sure

for i in dynamic_col;
     df = df.withColumn('propertiesMap', create_map( lit(i), col(i)))
```

Once all files got processed and appended into final dataframe it has to looklike

```
+-----+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
|id   |dept     |propertiesMap                                         |
+-----+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
|36636|Finance  |[salary -> 3000, location -> USA]                     |
|40288|Finance  |[salary -> 5000, location -> IND]                     |
|42114|Sales    |[salary -> 3900, location -> USA]                     |
|39192|Marketing|[salary -> 2500, location -> CAN]                     |
|34534|Sales    |[salary -> 6500, location -> USA]                     |
|36636|Finance  |[firstname -> kevin, lastname -> Miller]              |
|40288|Finance  |[firstname -> aaron, lastname -> sahn]                |
|42114|Sales    |[firstname -> daron, lastname -> ket]                 |
|39192|Marketing|[]                                                    |
|34534|Sales    |[firstname -> dev, lastname -> dis, middlename -> Sam]|
+-----+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

I don't use pandas.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of primitive datatypes like MapType() is to have a storied data structure. Instead of appending and doubling your df length I would ensure one row per id and dept. If thats so, then lets consider:

Original df

```
+-----+---------+---------------------------------+
|id   |dept     |propertiesMap                    |
+-----+---------+---------------------------------+
|36636|Finance  |{salary -> 3000, location -> USA}|
|40288|Finance  |{salary -> 5000, location -> IND}|
|42114|Sales    |{salary -> 3900, location -> USA}|
|39192|Marketing|{salary -> 2500, location -> CAN}|
|34534|Sales    |{salary -> 6500, location -> USA}|
+-----+---------+---------------------------------+
```

csv1 df

```
+-----+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|id   |dept     |propertiesMap_new                                       |
+-----+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|36636|Finance  |{firstname -> Miller, lastname -> kevin, middlename -> }|
|40288|Finance  |{firstname -> aaron, lastname -> sahn, middlename -> }  |
|42114|Sales    |{firstname -> daron, lastname -> ket, middlename -> }   |
|39192|Marketing|{firstname -> , lastname -> , middlename -> }           |
+-----+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

csv2 df

```
+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------+
|id   |dept |propertiesMap_new                                     |
+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------+
|34534|Sales|{firstname -> dev, lastname -> dis, middlename -> Sam}|
+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Depending on the size of the dataframes being added dynamically, you have two options, **1.** Either read and store them in a list first before appending to existing df. **2.** Loop as you read and append to existing df. Whichever option, all you need is a for loop. In this case, I used a list of df.
In the for loop **3.** union existing with new df. **4.** groupby and agg putting the target maptype column into an array. **5.** Leverage higher order function to cast array acquired above back into map.
See code below;

```
lst=[df2,df1]
for l in lst:
  df=df.union(l)
df.groupby('id','dept').agg(collect_list('propertiesMap').alias('propertiesMap')).select('id','dept',
        f.expr('aggregate(slice(propertiesMap, 2, size(propertiesMap)), propertiesMap[0], (acc, element) -> map_concat(acc, element))').alias('propertiesMap')
        ).show(truncate=False)



    +-----+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |id   |dept     |propertiesMap                                                                            |
    +-----+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |36636|Finance  |{salary -> 3000, location -> USA, firstname -> Miller, lastname -> kevin, middlename -> }|
    |40288|Finance  |{salary -> 5000, location -> IND, firstname -> aaron, lastname -> sahn, middlename -> }  |
    |42114|Sales    |{salary -> 3900, location -> USA, firstname -> daron, lastname -> ket, middlename -> }   |
    |39192|Marketing|{salary -> 2500, location -> CAN, firstname -> , lastname -> , middlename -> }           |
    |34534|Sales    |{salary -> 6500, location -> USA, firstname -> dev, lastname -> dis, middlename -> Sam}  |
    +-----+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try `map_concat` in pyspark for your requirement

```
str_dynamic_col = [location, ...]
int_dynamic_col =[salary, ...]

df=df.withColumn('INTpropertiesMap', F.create_map().cast(T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.IntegerType())))
df=df.withColumn('STRpropertiesMap', F.create_map().cast(T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())))

for i in str_dynamic_col:
     df = df.withColumn('STRpropertiesMap', 
          F.map_concat(
               F.col('STRpropertiesMap'),
               F.create_map( F.lit(i), F.col(i))
          )
     )

for i in int_dynamic_col:
     df = df.withColumn('INTpropertiesMap', 
          F.map_concat(
               F.col('INTpropertiesMap'),
               F.create_map( F.lit(i), F.col(i))
          )
     )
```

If looking for multiple datatypes with map, pls checkout this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/67088231/7224372